# Will Steroids Without Major Exercise Provide Moderate Gains?

Tags: testosterone

I'm wondering how/if the use of steroids without a work-out plan can result in muscle gain, fat loss, or etc. I'm not looking for massive gains, just moderate.

Comment: Short answer:  Yes, you will see muscle gain, but only in very small amounts. Without muscle fibre breakdown, there is no real window for the anabolic effect to take place.